# Simple Counting Function in Google Scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Just started learning how to write functions in Google Script Editor. Please help me fix my error. I'm also unable to get the Logger.log(var) function to produce anything in the log.

Goal of the function: count attendance based on whether an 'X' was listed next to a name. Currently the range being iterated through is hard coded. Is it possible to pass through a custom range when the function is called?

Thank you.

```
function attendance() {

  var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues();
  var count = 0
  for (n=6; n<12;++n){
    var cell = values[n][2];
    if (cell == "X"){
      count  = count +1;
    }
  }
  return (count);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the length of the values array to make it more dynamic.

```
n < values.length
```

Comment: would the function become: ``` function attendance(range) {```

Comment: I meant adding something akin to that line in your for loop. Im not sure the exact context of your data/function. Try using console.log() to look at some of your data so you can see what youre working with